# $R^2$ is not isometric to $R^3$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there a direct proof for showing that $R^2$ is not isometric to $R^3$ (with the usual metrics)? I know that they are not homeomorohic but I think there should be some direct and easy proof for showing that they are not isometric.

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ does not contain $4$ points that are all at distance $1$ from each other.

Comment: Similarly, an isometry $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ would induce a isometry $S^1 \to S^2$, which is forbidden for many reasons.

Comment: @ErickWong: This deserves to be an answer.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks, done :).

Answer (score 9):

In $\mathbb R^2$ there does not exist a configuration of $4$ points which are all at distance $1$ from each other.  This can be argued by elementary geometry: once we fix two such points, there are only two locations at which one can place another point to form an equilateral triangle, but the distance between those locations is not $1$.

On the other hand, in $\mathbb R^3$ this can be achieved with the vertices of a regular tetrahedron, so the two spaces are not isometric.

(This argument is reminiscent of a classic puzzle: how can you arrange 6 identical matchsticks to form 4 equilateral triangles?)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists an isometry $T:\mathbb R^3 \to\mathbb R^2$. Then $$T(\mathbf x)=\binom{\mathbf u}{\mathbf v}\mathbf x+\mathbf b\,,\text{ where } \,\mathbf{u,v,x}\in\mathbb R^3,\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf v=0,\text{ and }\, \mathbf b\in \mathbb R^2.$$Now notice that $|T(\mathbf u \times \mathbf v)-T(\mathbf 0)|=0\neq|(\mathbf u\times \mathbf v)-\mathbf 0|$, so $T$ doesn't preserve the distance between $(\bf u\,\times\,\bf v) $ and the origin. This a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, so your argument is: If $T \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is an affine map --- i.e., a map $T(\mathbf{x}) = L(\mathbf{x}) + \mathbf{b}$, where $L \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is linear --- then any vector $\mathbf{w}$ in the nullspace (kernel) of $L$ satisfies $T(\mathbf{w}) = \mathbf{b} = T(\mathbf{0})$, and hence $|T(\mathbf{w}) - T(\mathbf{0})| = 0$.  Thus (since the kernel of $L$ contains non-zero vectors), an affine map $T \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be an isometry.  And that's great, but how did you know that isometries must be affine?

Comment: @JesseMadnick  Let $T_0:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m $ be an origin fixing isometry. Then it must be that $T_0(\mathbf{v})=A\mathbf{v}$, where $A$ is an orthogonal $m\times n$ matrix and $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This can be seen by showing that $A\mathbf{v}\cdot A\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{u}$ iff $A$ is orthogonal. Since $T(\mathbf{v})-T(\mathbf{0})$ origin fixing, then there is an $A$ such that $T(\mathbf{v})-T(\mathbf{0})=A\mathbf{v}$, so $T(\mathbf{v})=A\mathbf{v}+T(\mathbf{0})$.

Comment: I'm not sure that quite answers my question, which is why an origin-fixing isometry $T_0 \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map.  (That is, why is a distance-preserving map that sends $0$ to $0$ necessarily linear?)  Yes, once you know that $T_0$ is linear, then of course $T_0(\mathbf{v}) = A\mathbf{v}$ for some orthogonal matrix $A$, and the rest follows.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Oh, sorry I didn't understand your question before. If $T_0$ is an origin fixing isometry, then $|T_0(\mathbf{v})|=|T_0(\mathbf{v})-T_0(\mathbf{0})|=|\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{0}|=|\mathbf{v}|$, and so $2\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{u}|^2+|\mathbf{v}|^2-|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}|^2= |T_0(\mathbf{u})|^2+|T_0(\mathbf{v})|^2-|T_0(\mathbf{u})-T_0(\mathbf{v})|^2= 2T_0(\mathbf{u})\cdot T_0(\mathbf{v})$. With this, we can expand $|T_0(\mathbf{u}+\alpha\mathbf{v})-(\,T_0(\mathbf{u})+\alpha T_0(\mathbf{v})\,)|^2$ to get $0$, showing that $T_0$ is linear.